# Not possible to set user Profile status (slack api users.profile.set method)

Tags: javascript, typescript, slack-api

Hi I would like to update profile information of slack account using API.
I used WebClient using user token, setting profile:write scope.
I set Slack Bot subscribing slack events, but it only updated my profile. Whoever tried to update his/her profile, my(slack bot authorizer) profile updated. There is already user params in set method.

```js
await client.users.profile.set({
user,
profile: {
    status_emoji,
    status_text,
} as any,
})
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors when the method fails to update others' profiles?

Comment: There was not any error before. I changed log level from debug to info and get an API error: not_admin.

Comment: Ahh yes looks like there might be a setting on your workspace which restricts editing user profiles to Workspace Admins only. A bot is not an admin so it won't be able to edit other users' profiles except for yours. You will need to use an xoxp token that belongs to an admin user.